# How to use slideout.js using reactjs and webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

Slideout.js library demands you to execute it on page load. But I am not able to understand where and how can I write this custom JS code in my react jsx code.

```
<script>
  var slideout = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70
  });
</script>
```

As per documentation on https://slideout.js.org I need to write down above code in my html file or JS file. Please tell me how can we write this code in our JSX or react js file.

My code for `Header.js` is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router} from 'react-router'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import slideout from 'slideout';

class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav id="menu">
                <header>
                    <h2>Menu</h2>
                </header>
            </nav>

            <main id="panel">
                <header>
                    <h2>Panel</h2>
                </header>
            </main>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it into the componentDidMount method of the component. componentDidMount is triggered after the first render, so the elements are already on the DOM by then.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.slideout = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in ComponentWillMount in the Header.js page. ComponentWillMount is a Reactjs Component Life cycle which will execute before rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

React is used for manage VDOM before html document render. Try using [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for control virtual node.
`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.slideout = new Slideout({
      'panel': this.refs._panel,
      'menu': this.refs._menu,
      'padding': 256,
      'tolerance': 70
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav ref="_menu">
            <header>
              <h2>Menu</h2>
            </header>
        </nav>
        <main ref="_panel">
            <header>
              <h2>Panel</h2>
            </header>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
```